issue with routing in vanilla php
as a beginner in php I've stumbled upon this issue with php routing.
I had created index.php file and other php files needed for my project, however when I go to / or /product for example it returns an error.
My index.php code:
<?php

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ($request) {
    case "/":
        require "home.php";
        break;
    case "/dashboard":
        require "dashboard.php";
        break;
    case "/product":
        require "product.php";
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        break;
    }

?>

.htaccess configuration:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]


I'm also using xampp, folder name of my project is test just so there's no any confusion.
Any help is appreciated, I'm pretty much beginner at php
[![enter image description here][3]][3]


The path you are testing /test/ is not accounted for in the switch. You should also probably account for absence/presence of trailing slashes. Instead of issuing a raw 404, consider outputting verbose debugging information at this stage.

On a side note, every tutorial insists on using mod_rewrite for this purpose but it's the most complex and counter-intuitive tool, and a total overkill for this. A simple FallbackResource directive will work just fine.

test != TEST, at least not if you are using an OS with a case-sensitive file system.

add /test/ into the case instead of /, If u add, it thinks that the homepage is / which means the root of the directory which is localhost

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
